# Show that $\|x\|_{1}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} \text { and }\|x\|_{\infty}=\max _{i=1, \ldots, n} x_{i}$ is not defined not strictly convex space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Show that the vector space $\mathbb{C^n}$ with the either of the norms $$
\|x\|_{1}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_{i}| \text { and }\|x\|_{\infty}=\max _{i\in\{1, \ldots, n\}} |x_{i}|
$$ is not strictly convex.

I am trying to think about a counter example and thus show that $$||U+V|| \neq ||U||+||V||$$
for $v=tU$ or $u=tV$ for $t\in \mathbb{R}$ but I couldnt find any counter example.

Comment: For the unit ball in the $1$ norm, consider the line between $e_1$ and $e_2$. For the unit ball in the $\infty$ norm, consider the line between $\sum_{i=1}^n e_i$ and $-e_n +sum_{i=1}^{n-1} e_i$. (It would help to have a picture here; you could draw things in 2 dimensions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x_1=(1,0)$ , $x_2=(1,1)$ for both norm, I guess ?

Comment: true, I did not realize the question as it should be. I thought on something much more complicated

Answer (score 0):

A norm is strictly convex if and only if the unit ball does not contain intervals.
Take $x_1=(1,0,\dots,0)$ and $x_2=(0,1,\dots,0)$. Then for every $0\leq t\leq 1$
the vector $v_t=tx_1+(1-t)x_2=(t,1-t,\dots,0)$ satisfies $\|v_t\|_1=1$, so that norm is not strictly convex. Now take $y_1=(1,1,\dots,0), y_2=(1,0,\dots,0)$. Then for every $0\leq t\leq 1$ the vector $u_t=ty_1+(1-t)y_2=(1,t,\dots,0)$ satisfies $\|u_t\|_{\infty}=1$, so both unit balls contains intervals in their boundaries.